# This subgroup is contained in every sylow $p$-subgroup of the group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

This question is from an assignment which I tried earlier. For Background, I have done a graduate course on group theory and have studied sylow theorems in detail.

> If $H$ is a normal subgroup of order $p^k$ of a finite group $G$, then $H$ is contained in every Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.

I am sorry but I am at loss of ideas on which result should I use.

I think  the statement sylow $p$-subgroup is unique that's why it is normal need not necessary be true though the statement if unique sylow $p$-subgroup exists then it is normal holds and is well known.

Can you please give some hints?

Comment: It's contained in some Sylow subgroup, and they are all conjugate, so it's contained in all of them.

Comment: By the way, the title of your post does not seem to match the question you are asking.

Comment: @DerekHolt Sorry. I have edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$gHg^{-1}=H.\,\,\,\forall g\in G.$

If $K_{1},K_{2}...K_{n}$ be the sylow p-subgroups then by Sylow's 2nd Theorem we know that $H$ is contained in some $K_{i}$ say $K_{m}$.

Also We know from Sylow Theorems that all the Sylow-p-subgroups are conjugates.

Hence We can denote the collection $K_{1},K_{2}...K_{n}$ in the following way as $K,g_{1}Kg_{1}^{-1},...,g_{n-1}Kg_{n-1}^{-1}$. for some $g_{i}$'s in $G$. Where $K$ is the subgroup which contains $H$ from above , i.e. $K_{m}$.

But We have $g_{i}Hg_{i}^{-1}=H\,\,\,\,\forall i\in\{1,2,...,n-1\}$.

So $g_{i}Hg_{i}^{-1}=H$ is a subgroup of all $g_{i}Kg_{i}^{-1}$. So, $H$ is contained in all Sylow p subgroups.

PS:- I am not going by the wikipedia definition of Sylow Theorems. I am using the defintions in **Gallian**.

There Sylow's 2nd theorem is :- If H is a p-subgroup(having order of power p) then H is contained in some Sylow p-subgroup.

Sylow 3rd Theorem:- The order of G is $p^{k}m$ where $gcd(p,m)=1$ . Then if the number of Sylow p-Subgroups is n, then $n\equiv 1\mod p$ and $n|m$. Furthermore, all the sylow p subgroups are conjugate to each other.

Sylow 1st Theorem is the same as that in wiki.

Answer (score 2):

We can also reason like this without Sylow's theorem.

If $H$ is a normal $p$-subgroup of $G$ and $P$ is any other p-subgroup, then $HP$ is a $p$-subgroup of $G$ (this follows from the fact that $H$ is normal and from the formula $|HP|=|H|\cdot|P|/|P\cap H|$). It is also clear that $P\leq PH$.

It follows that if $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup then $P=PH$ and hence $H\leq P$.